# sql command conditional insert

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Sample table records

```
objId   ; objCode  
19-1    ;   TE  
19-2    ;   TE  
19-1    ;   KKK    
19-3    ;   DA  
19-4    ;   TE
```

How can be inserted  KKK code to objs with objId 19-2 and 19-4 by SQL command.
Two conditions are objs must have TE and must not have KKK.
I succeed similar recording by C#.
But i want to learn whether or not can be succeed by SQL

Comment: Can you specify the expected result too?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into your_table (objId, objCode)
select objId, 'KKK'
from your_table
group by objId
having sum(case when objCode = 'TE' then 1 end) > 0
   and sum(case when objCode = 'KKK' then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use do an `insert ... select ...` with a filter on `objCode = 'TE'` and a not exists condition on `objCode = 'KKK'`:

```
insert into mytable
select objId, 'KKK'
from mtytable t
where objCode = 'TE'
and not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.objId = t.objId and t1.objCode = 'KKK'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in `insert` to get the rows that you want:

```
insert into t (objId, objCode)
    select t.objId, 'KKK'
    from t
    where t.objCode = 'TE' and
          not exists (select 1
                      from t t2
                      where t2.objId = t.objId and t2.objCode = 'TE'
                     );
```